# How do you extract texts into a text format that you can copy and paste from visual novels?

Tags: resources

Let's say you want to extract texts from the visual novel for the purpose of looking up the word in the dictionary, or feeding them into a machine translator. How would one go about accomplishing this?

Comment: I suppose you mean Japanese words?

Comment: @Alenanno From context, most VN's are in Japanese, so yes, Japanese words.

Comment: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-questions-about-technical-aspects-of-visual-novels-on-topic in case if anyone wants to discuss if these type of questions are on-topic

Comment: I voted +1 to undo the -1, because I think VN and Anime are part of the same culture and market.

Answer (score 8):

There are some software, such as [Anime Games Text Hooker](https://sites.google.com/site/agthook/) or [Interactive Text Hooker](http://www.hongfire.com/forum/showthread.php/208860-Interactive-Text-Hooker-new-text-extraction-tool), that are especially made for this purpose. Some people use them together with automated translation tools.

[An AGTH tutorial](http://www.hongfire.com/forum/showthread.php/59189-AGTH-TRANSLATOR-AGGREGATOR-ILLUSTRATED-GUIDE), and an example screenshot of how it looks in action:
[image: AGTH]

[An ITH tutorial](http://www.craneanime.com/2011/01/tutorial-ith-interactive-text-hooker.html), and an example screenshot of how it looks in action:
[image: ITH]